# error: 'struct msghdr' has no member named 'msg_accrights' is the message while compiling C program

Tags: c

Migrating from Sun Solaris to RHEL. But while compiling the C program getting the following errors.

```
struct msghdr msg;

    msg.msg_accrights = (caddr_t)&fd_to_send;
    msg.msg_accrightslen = sizeof(int);

error: 'struct msghdr' has no member named 'msg_accrights'

error: 'struct msghdr' has no member named 'msg_accrightslen'
```

The Linux setup is running kernel 2.6.18-419.el5.

Comment: Incidentally, why are you porting to RHEL 5? That’s been obsolete for over a year...

Answer (score 3):

Your Solaris code is using 4.3BSD-style messages; Linux uses [4.4BSD-style messages](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendmsg.2.html), with `msg_control` and `msg_controllen` and [`struct cmsg`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/cmsg.3.html) instead of `msg_accrights`.

You’ll need to modify your code to pass file descriptors using the approach described in [How to use sendmsg() to send a file-descriptor via sockets between 2 processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8481138/4500798)